# What's the standard print size for a sectional chart?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts

I'm checking out the Dallas sectional in digital form for my own amusement. The image, in TIFF format, is massive. I wonder, if you buy one of these in printed form from the FAA (or your local GA office), what would be the sheet size of the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The New York Sectional (the only paper one I have on hand right now) is 20 3/4 X 59 1/4 inches. You are correct, they are large and printed on nice thick paper.

Comment: And take ages to fold for the first time!

Comment: But is helpful for beating back a lizard stowaway in a glider.